# Fragment doesn't display

Tags: android, android-fragments

The project is multiple-fragment project. Launch application to start BaseActivity, which all fragments are attached into it.

Issue:

Fragment A is the first fragment and is launched very well.
Fragment B is trigged by clicking button of Fragment A, also launched very well.
During from B back to A, the problem occurs. Nothing to display, only background, the BaseActivity.

All fragments use the api "replace" to display, although this API may produce performance problems, please ignore it firstly.

I have tried many methods, but nothing works.

The launched fragment method shows below:

```
    public void navigateToFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean isClear){
        if(isClear){     
            getSupportFragmentManager()
          .popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .replace(R.id.container,fragment)
            .commit()
}
```

As I know, popBackStack and replace, commit can lead to one fragment is launched twice, but why no display after replace whatever I replace it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if you want to add fragment in back stack then you have to use add method instead of replace and popbackstack work for you. But, if you don't want to add it in backstack then from back to Fragmnet b you have replace again popbackstack not work for you

Comment: actually, i don't think this method is a better one.
i am puzzled why first is ok, second is not ok, both use `replace`

Answer (score 0):

try use `add` instead of `replace`

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .add(R.id.container,fragment)
        .commit()
```

Comment: whole project use `replace`, almost now is the end of this project.
If use `add` instead `replace`, it is hard to fix in whole project.
This project uses nearly 30+ fragments, which all use `replace`.
I just in this project to face this problem T T.

Comment: If i use `add`, i need to think about `hide`.